# What should my package-manager-like command line tool print to stdout/stderr?

Tags: linux, colors, stdout, stdin, messaging

I'm working on a project that will use whatever package manager is available to provision a freshly installed OS. Some examples of package managers could be `apt` for Ubuntu, `brew` and `brew cask` for OSX, or `pacman` for Arch.

I'd like to display colored messages to stdout or stderr depending on what happens. I'm looking for some guidelines about what type of color and content I should use and where I should pipe the output.

Thinking a little bit about it I came up with:

- status messages can be in blue or no color and only printed to stdout if the `-v` or `--verbose` flag is given.

  Ex:

  ```
  -* installing commandline-tools
  ```
- Success messages in green and printed by default to stdout (or maybe if the verbose flag is given I'm not sure)

  Ex:

  ```
  -* installed commandline-tools
  ```
- Failure messages in red and printed by default to stderr

  Ex:

  ```
  -* failed to install commandline-tools
  ```

Thoughts and opinions are welcome, but I would also appreciate some definitive sources/guidelines

Comment: When you say "provision a freshly installed OS" what do you mean by that? With this tool be run in an `initrd`? Will it try to overwrite the current local disk? Will it create a `chroot` environment? Also, how do you intend to dynamically use a package manager? Package managers require packages in particular formats, so are you including a copy of many types of packages? Or dynamically building the packages in your tool?

Comment: Check out what `ansible` output looks like?  +1 for finishing with a count of errors.  The green messages for "ok" tend to have the same text, (like `ok [localhost]`, on a line of it's own), maybe it makes them easier to skim.  The name of the task is in normal color.  The defaults seem to be that you _do_ want output for successes, to provide progress indicators, because these tasks take sooo longgg.  Not entirely sure that separating stdout / stderr is useful here.  It's most useful as a separate channel from tools used in pipelines, but you kind of want to keep the whole log output together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet, you will be able to color what you want :

```
for i in {0..7};
do
    tput setaf $i // color next echo command
    echo "tput setaf $i"
    tput sgr0     // reset normal colors
done
```

I recommend to *not* use raw ANSI escape code.

Comment: The original project I've been looking at uses raw ANSI escape codes, can you elaborate on why you recommend not going that route?